# Keep URL safe from search search engine results

Tags: domain-name-system, web-hosting, directory, url

I've tried to ask this a few times but I think readers are missing the problem, so I'm rewording it.

I'm aiming to create a set of online `TRUE` lifestyle zines - Meaning that they cover a number of different topics based on my own lifestyle - Some of which are related, but a lot of which are not. For example:

- Some are about Music, Fashion, Food/Drink, Places, etc, etc.
- Some are about my own photography projects ( Ranging from nature to
  boudour/mature photography )
- Some are about technology and my work as a freelancer
- Some about models ( Again Rated `G` up to `R` )

In short, I'd like to host all of these under a single domain `( http://example-zines.com )`, but I would prefer that they are all initially hidden from the public eye.

So, a homepage that lists all zines would not be a good idea, and it would be impractical to registed a new domain for each series of zines that I create.

Meaning, the most logical solution would be to make the homepage of `example-zines` a blank/logo only page, and to have all zines inside a subdirectory such as `/view/`. I would also use `<meta name="robots" content="noindex,nofollow">` in all zines to keep them from being listed on search engines.

The only problem would be : if a reader copies and pastes the url of one of my zines into a third party site (forum/facebook/pinterest), some of my zines could potentially get found if someone did a search for `http://example-zines.com`.

What I mean is:

If you do a search on `GOOGLE` for `"http://example.com"` : You will see thousands of results like:

```
Redirecting from http://example.com to https://www.example.com ...
https://www.digitalocean.com › community › questions › redirecting-from...
7 Jun 2017 - I want to redirect my domain from 'http://example.com' to 'https://www.example.com' and if right in search example.com to redirect to ...
```

Meaning that even if my site uses all of the nessessary `<meta>` tags to stop it being listed, details about individual zines can still be found using this method.

Is there any way to prevent this?

Obviously, using bitly to initially share your links is a good way of doing it, but not all users will do this. Is there a solution?

Answer (score 1):

If `topic-one.example.com`  and `topic-two.example.com` will work, simply create extra host names in your DNS and use the named host support in the web server (apache2, nginx, etc).

Using named hosts, you can serve content based on multiple names from the same directory or from different directories.

Depending on how your blog software is written, it could pick up themes, database entry hints, etc from the `$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']` or equivalent variable set by the host name in the HTTP GET/POST headers.